# twilio php Sequential Dialing Logic

Tags: php, twilio

I am writing an application for [twilio in PHP](https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install) and I need some help with the logic or what I can do..I am somewhat stuck in the logic process you could say.

I was wondering if there is a function in Twilio or any feature that allows you to keep track of how many times you have made calls in one session. I am making a Sequential Dialling application and if I can keep track of how many times a call was failed to be picked up or was busy then that can be used to call the next number. A possibility is to use a counter...

something like

$R++ at the beginning of the action URL code so each time that action url is executed it adds 1 which tells you how many times a call has failed but the problem with that as well is that each time the action url runs it starts the variable $R as a new value or as 0 and so the $R isn't stored which prevents us from telling how many calls were made.

My Current code is:

```
<?php
    require "twilio.php";

    // initiate response library
    $response = new Response();

    header("content-type: text/xml");
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";


$PhoneNumbers= array('4167641543','6478604858');


?>

<Response>
<Say voice="woman">Calling the first person</Say>
<Dial action="handle-key.php" method="POST" timeout="15"> <?php echo $PhoneNumbers[0] ?> </Dial>

</Response>
```

----------------------handle-key.php----------------------------------

```
   <?php
        require "twilio.php";

        // initiate response library
        $response = new Response();

        header("content-type: text/xml");
        echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";


    $PhoneNumbers= array('4167641543','6478604858');


        if(($_REQUEST['DialStatus'] == "busy" || $_REQUEST['DialCallStatus'] == "no-answer" || $_REQUEST['DialCallStatus'] == "failed" || $_REQUEST['DialCallStatus'] == "canceled")) {

           $variableToCall=$PhoneNumbers[1];

        }

        $R++;

    ?>

    <Response>
    <Say voice="woman">Calling the first person</Say>
    <Dial action="handle-key.php" method="POST" timeout="15"> <?php echo $PhoneNumbers[1] ?> </Dial>
    <Say voice="woman"> <?php $R=0; ?> </Say>
    </Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than increment $R, you could increment a (MySQL, for example) database value...

If you need to keep that value persistent for an entire call, then you could associate the value with the call's cookie.

Kyle mentioned over in [GetSatisfaction](http://getsatisfaction.com/twilio/topics/how_does_twilio_handle_cookies_sessions):

> When making phone calls, Twilio treats each call as a new session.
>   Cookies will persist for the duration of the call; however, once the
>   call is finished, cookies will be disposed.

If you need to keep that value persistent for the life of a user, then you could associate the value with the caller's phone number.